# Pandas value_counts for a column based on value of different column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe 'students' that looks like the following:

```
         Cumulative.GPA  Athlete
     0   3.9             Yes
     1   3.3             Yes
     2   4.0             No
     3   3.6             Yes
```

I'm trying to get a value_counts table of GPAs separated into two columns: 1 for athletes and 1 for non-athletes. Output should look like this (with leftmost column obviously continuing down to 0.0)

```
               Cumulative.GPA.athlete   Cumulative.GPA.nonathlete
        4.0    0                        1
        3.9    1                        0
        3.8    0                        0
        3.7    0                        0
        3.6    1                        0
        3.5    0                        0
        3.4    0                        0
        3.3    1                        0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to count the frequencies of Athlete vs non-athlete GPA then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to add missing GPA increments then [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to make the output match the expected:

```
res = (
    pd.crosstab(df['Cumulative.GPA'], df['Athlete'])
        .reindex(index=np.arange(40, 33 - 1, -1) / 10,
                 columns=['Yes', 'No'],
                 fill_value=0)
        .rename(columns={'Yes': 'Cumulative.GPA.athlete',
                         'No': 'Cumulative.GPA.nonathlete'})
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

*Using `int` steps to avoid any precision issues

`res`:

```
     Cumulative.GPA.athlete  Cumulative.GPA.nonathlete
4.0                       0                          1
3.9                       1                          0
3.8                       0                          0
3.7                       0                          0
3.6                       1                          0
3.5                       0                          0
3.4                       0                          0
3.3                       1                          0
```

---

If wanting the shown GPA range to be dynamic, instead of hardcoded bounds, [`Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) and [`Series.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) can be used to set the reindexing bounds as recommended by [U12-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430002/15497888):

```
res = (
    pd.crosstab(df['Cumulative.GPA'], df['Athlete'])
        .reindex(index=np.arange(int(df['Cumulative.GPA'].max() * 10),
                                 int(df['Cumulative.GPA'].min() * 10) - 1,
                                 -1) / 10,
                 columns=['Yes', 'No'],
                 fill_value=0)
        .rename(columns={'Yes': 'Cumulative.GPA.athlete',
                         'No': 'Cumulative.GPA.nonathlete'})
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

---

Setup Used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cumulative.GPA': [3.9, 3.3, 4.0, 3.6],
    'Athlete': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']
})
```